# Is it possible to run package.json scripts from a Node script?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I have several task in my package.json like:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "test:ci": "jest --runInBand --no-cache --watch false --coverage true",
    "test:codecov": "codecov",
    "tsc:check": "tsc --noEmit",
    "prettier:check": "pretty-quick --staged"
    .
    .
    . // a lot more here
}
```

I am trying to build a build script that depends on those tasks but write it as a new script in `package.json` is too verbose and hard to read.

Is there some way to run those scripts from a `build.js` file? so I can chain/redo those tasks and also get some error handling.

Comment: Have you tried to just run `npm run <script_name>` in your `build.js` file?

Comment: No, but that is not valid javascript.

Comment: Correct, it's bash indeed. You have to write code to run script bash ```const process = require('child_process');
 process.exec('npm run ...')
```

Comment: That is actually a good idea @anh-nguyen. I will try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @anh-nguyen [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54323170/is-it-possible-to-run-packaje-json-scripts-from-a-node-script?noredirect=1#comment95465316_54323170) I did this initial raw structure on how to be able to do what I wanted I hope this helps somebody.

Notice that instead of `process` and `process.exec` I am using [shelljs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs) because I already had it as dependency but you could change them if needed.

```
// tslint:disable:no-string-literal
const shell = require('shelljs');
const path = require('path');
const rootDir = process.cwd();
const distBundlesDir = path.join(rootDir, 'dist-bundles');
const objectWithRawScripts = require(path.join(rootDir, 'package.json')).scripts;

const packageScripts = {
  build: objectWithRawScripts['build'],
  prettierCheck: objectWithRawScripts['prettier:check'],
  tscCheck: objectWithRawScripts['tsc:check'],
};

function runScript(scriptToRun) {
  try {
    shell.echo(`Running ${scriptToRun}`);
    shell.exec(scriptToRun);
  } catch (e) {
    shell.echo('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
    shell.echo(`there was an error with ${scriptToRun}`);
    console.error(e);
    shell.echo('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

shell.echo('Init Tasks');
runScript(packageScripts.prettierCheck);
runScript(packageScripts.tscCheck);
```